# Reusing LED from RC helicopter controller

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I have an old RC helicopter controller, but not the helicopter.  I recently purchased an Arduino Uno and would like to do something with LEDs(beside the on-board one built-in). Can I use an LED from the controller, that is already soldered in, cut it free and plug into my breadboard.

*Side Note*

I have no experience in soldering and don't own a soldering iron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. For convenience, cut a bit shorter the lead on the side of the package where the flat part is so that you can identify the leads easier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Make sure you have a resistor in series with your led. It is much, much better to guess and use the wrong resistor, than not to put a resistor in at all. I use http://led.linear1.org/1led.wiz to calculate my resistor. Your source voltage will be 5v. Each thing you have to fill has help on what value you're likely to want to put here.

It doesn't matter which side of the led you put the resistor.

If you can cut the led out, it should be fine, so long as you have long enough legs to go into the breadboard.

Answer (score 0):

Ignacio's drawing shows you how to connect a LED. If you don't have any soldering tools you can use a **solderless breadboard**. [This small one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/65) from Adafruit is ideal for small circuits:

[image]

(They exist in all sizes from very small to very large). The holes in each 5-hole row are all internally connected.

The problem with cutting the LED from the board may be that the remaining wire length is too short to fit in the breadboard. (You'll need at least something like 6 mm.) LEDs are a nice way to start with electronics, since you need minimal part count to make something visible. If you can't cannibalize the LED from the controller, just buy one from your local electronics shop. They're dirt cheap.